# Chrome: Permissive adblocker, that whitelists pages by default?

Tags: chrome, ad-blocker

A lot of webpages contain overblown advertising, so in general I want to use an adblocker. However, I'd prefer adblockers to allow me blacklisting webpages that overdo it rather than whitelisting those that don't, in order not to damage the ad-revenue of webpages that put in non-obtrusive advertising.

As far as I know common ad-blockers don't support this properly. E.g. in AdBlock Plus one can set a whilelist rule `*` to whitelist everything by default, but if I then click to enable the adblocker on a specific webpage, the `*` rule is removed and adblocking becomes enabled for all pages again.

Better yet, an adblocker should allow blocking specific annoying ad elements such as autoplay videos even on whitelisted / not blacklisted pages. AdBlock Plus allows blacklisting elements manually, but again only if adblocking is enabled in general.

Is there some adblocker for Chrome that has such permissive default behaviour?

Comment: Meanwhile, Google Chrome is kind of forcing the issue to some degree, though sadly space-wasting permanently-in-view ad-banners have not made it on the list of intrusive ads on mobile...